# MSSQL Server 2012 and extended stored procedure from a C++ dll

Tags: c++, sql-server, stored-procedures, dll

I was assigned a new task at work. I need to update a very old C++ project. The last time this project was modified was way back in 2006.

Now, this C++ project compiles a dll that is used as an extended stored procedure. This dll was installed on the SQL server and used as a stored procedure.

Our SQL server will be upgraded to the 2012 version and the dll needs to be updated to 64-bit.

Is this something that is still supported by the MSSQL Server 2012? Does it still support calling an extended stored procedure from a C++ dll?

Thanks,

Charles-Antoine Caron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for extended stored procedure is still there in SQL2012 and SQL2016, with the following caveat:

> This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL
>   Server. Do not use this feature in new development work, and modify
>   applications that currently use this feature as soon as possible. Use
>   CLR Integration instead.

See the [documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164653(v=sql.110).aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164653(v=sql.110).aspx)

If porting to the CLR is too complicated, you could facade the C++ dll using Pinvoke in C#.

Comment: Hello,

Very happy to say that SQL Server Stored Procedure, using CLR and C#, are working like a charm :-)

Here are some links that helped me:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5czye81z(v=vs.100).aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/884807/CLR-Stored-Procedure-in-SQL-Server

Note that for Visual Studio 2013 Express, I had to install the SDDT update.